# while decoding email from gmail account using php Imap

Tags: php

while decoding email from gmail account  using php Imap class I am getting some chars like 
=C2=A0=20
but all mails from  others working fine. Any one can Help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is solvable with imap_qprint:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-qprint.php